# Adding a object from one array to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have 3 tables. The first is displaying seven weekdays, the second is displaying what ever is in the array connected to the day, and the last is a list with different strings, which i want to be able to click on, and then add to the previous selected day array.

```
mondayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tuesdayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
wedensdayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
thursdayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
fridayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
saturdayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
sundayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Sætter ugedage op
Weekdays *mandag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Mandag" daylist:mondayArray];
Weekdays *tirsdag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Tirsdag" daylist:tuesdayArray];
Weekdays *onsdag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Onsdag" daylist:wedensdayArray];
Weekdays *torsdag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Torsdag" daylist:thursdayArray];
Weekdays *fredag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Fredag" daylist:fridayArray];
Weekdays *lordag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Lørdag" daylist:saturdayArray];
Weekdays *sondag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Søndag" daylist:sundayArray];
```

In another implementation file (InfoTable) i use the arrays to create the tables:

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [dayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Then in the last implementation file, i tries to add to that array at didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
    InfoTable *appDelegate = (InfoTable *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSString *temp;
    // Gives me the item from the list i clicked
    temp = [dagListe objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Tries to add the above 'temp' to the array.
    [appDelegate.dayList addObject:temp];
```

I can't seem to find the error, and when i run it i get:

```
-[VisueltSkemaAppDelegate dayList]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x58241d0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be `appDelegate.dayList`. It is telling you that it can't find a property called `dayList` in your application delegate. Did you add a property for it, or is it just an instance variable?

Did this show up as a warning when you built? The compiler should have caught this for you. It's always a good idea to pay attention (and fix!) compiler warnings. Just because Xcode lets you ignore them and run your app anyway, doesn't mean you should. :)

Comment: And no, there was/is no warnings. Using X4. :)

Comment: in your pastebin code, daylist is a property of InfoTable and not of the appdelegate.

Comment: Fluchtpunkt: Yes, but i thought that made no difference. How could i approach it then?

Comment: @Bob: None of this code shows your app delegate. Does it have a `dayList` property?

Comment: @Bob: Just noticed you are casting your app delegate to `InfoTable`. Is that really the class of your app delegate? Which file contains `applicationDidFinishLaunching`? Or another way to check... if you open MainWindow.xib, then click on the orange cube called "App Delegate", what class & file does it show you in the Quick Help?

Comment: @Skue Hmm, i see that now aswell. In the mainwindow.xib it says: Name: VisueltSkemaAppDelegate, declared in: VisueltSkemaAppDelegate.h.

Comment: Then that's the problem. VisueltSkemaAppDelegate is your app delegate. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` returns the **application's** delegate, which isn't `InfoTable`. If you need to change `InfoTable` then you need to refer to it some other way.

Comment: Thanks, skue. However i am not currently so sure what my possibilities is now then, i will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added @synthesize to the implementation file for the property declared in the header?

Comment: Yes, i have added @synthesize. I dont belive it is that causing the trouble.